# How to perform some actions on each value from a drop down using selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to perform some actions on each value from a drop down using selenium java?
I am using below code. Please help.

```
WebElement bldgs=Fn_GetWebElement(CreateSSIObject.getProperty("Bldgselect"));
Select  Bldg_select=new Select(bldgs);

List<WebElement> dropdownvalues = Bldg_select.getOptions();

int count=dropdownvalues.size();
System.out.println("Toatl number of values are :"+count);

    for(int i=1;i<26;i++)
    {       
        if(dropdownvalues.get(i).isEnabled())
        {
             dropdownvalues.get(i).click();
             System.out.println("Not Working :"+i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey neelam. can you clear a bit in detail what actually you want to do.

Comment: I want select each value from a drop down list and perform some actions on it. In my code I am just trying to print value of i till it count to 26(26 is the actual size in my code). SO I have tried with variable count and as well as with the hard coded value. Its just printing 1st vale from the drop down. Its not taking any value from the drop down.

Comment: @NeelamSharma - is ur list of weblements is filling with all options in drop down ? also try dropdownvalues.get(i).getText(); once to see if all elements are printing or not and share if u see any error during code execution ... do u see any stale element reference after first option is clicked ?

Comment: Can you comment `dropdownvalues.get(i).click();` and try

Comment: How can you select all the values from drop down manually at one shot?

Comment: Are you trying to select the values in the drop down one by one?

Comment: Why are you using the `Select` class and then clicking elements? You should spend some time reading the docs on the `Select` class and how to efficiently use it. You also need to clarify what you are actually trying to accomplish. As it is now, your intent is not clear.

Comment: @NarendraR  thanks that works.

Answer (score 0):

In order to select an option from select drop down, we need to call the methods on the select instance instead of the webelements.

For Eg,

```
Select  Bldg_select=new Select(bldgs);
Bldg_select.selectByIndex(4); // selects 4th element in the drop down
```

you can't use click on the available options in the drop down, and this needs to be handled by using the select instance that we had created.

Refer this link to get an idea of various available options for selection a value in the drop down.[Selenium Select Drop Down Options](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/dropdown-multiple-select-operations/).

Thanks.

Comment: You *can* use click... it just isn't as convenient and defeats the purpose of using the `Select` class in the first place.

Comment: click doesn't work if the element is not visible. Options will be collapsed by default.

Comment: It's strange but it actually does work. You can execute a click on an option when the SELECT is closed and it will work. You can try it yourself and see.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just print the values present in drop-down use following code, there's no need to click each item & select as `.getOptions()` already does that for you (i.e. fetches all the values inside Select Tag) so you can just traverse through the list and `getText()` of each element in the list.

```
for(int i=1;i<26;i++)
    {       

       System.out.println("Not Working :"+ dropdownvalues.get(i).getText());

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a click to expand the dropdown before trying to select the option. Meaning it will be trying to click on an element that's not visible. Add in:

```
bldgs.click();
```

Before your if to expand the dropdown

Comment: Click isn't necessary when using `Select` class... you can just select the option you want using the provided methods.

Comment: He's not working with the select class when trying to click though, he starts with the Select class as Bldg_select, but then pulls out the options to be stored as a WebElement list, and it's those WebElements he's trying to click, not through the Select object